# Can't copy newly created objects in the Class constructor to its vector member in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, scope, copy

In the class constructor, I am initializing other objects and pushing these objects to my class vector member. From what I understand, the vector create a copy of the object and stores it so that it doesn't go out of scope. However, when verifying the objects in another class function, they are not initialized anymore. Here's a example code to explain the behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Square {
    private:
    int size_ = 0;
    int colour_ = 0;

    public:
    Square(){
        size_ = 0;
        colour_ = 0;
    }
    void init(int size, int colour) {
        size_ = size;
        colour_ = colour;
    }
    int get_size() { return size_; }
};


class SetSquares {
    private:
    std::vector<Square> squares_;
    int number_;

    public:
    SetSquares(): number_(0) {}
    void init(int num) {
        number_ = num;
        squares_.clear();
        squares_.resize(num);
        for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
            Square square;
            square.init(i, i);
            squares_.push_back(square);
        }
    }

    void sample(int i) {
        if (i >= number_) { return; }
        std::cout << "Square size is: " << squares_[i].get_size() <<       std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SetSquares set_of_squares;
    set_of_squares.init(7);
    set_of_squares.sample(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `squares_.push_back(square)` do `squares_[i] = square;`

Comment: The resize line was the issue, as mentioned below by Tomek. Removing that line and keeping the push_back worked too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

resize(n) will create n default constructed elements in a vector and push_back will append new elements after those n elements. Use reserve and push_back or resize and index operator as suggested in comment.